# How to clear ALL items from Safari's reading list?

Tags: icloud, safari, mobile-safari, reading-list

How to clear ALL items from Safari's reading list?
I have 100's of items in the list so do not want do do them individually.

I tried removing `Bookmarks.plist` in `~/Library/Safari/` which deletes the reading list on the mac locally but iCloud just adds them back, when syncing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this not work? Seems to for me.

[image: Clear All]

Comment: Yes this work, must have missed it since, it not on the iPad or iPhone

Comment: Oh, I see. I only ever use it on the desktop, so I was a little confused about it now working for you.

Comment: I don't have this in Safari Mac (7.0.6).

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco They moved it to a contextual menu. Right click on any item and you'll get an option to clear all.

Comment: @funroll - Thank you for the tip. This is a rather weird use for a contextual menu.

Answer (score 10):

In more recent Safari versions where the button has gone away, just right-click or Control-click an item in the list. The context menu will show a Clear all… choice there.

Comment: Thanks the answer above no longer works on Sarari 9.

Comment: I confirm that this solution works on macOS Big Sur

Answer (score -2):

Swipe item on list you want to delete. Delete option will appear.