# Removing items from Reading List in OS X/Safari

Tags: safari, reading-list

How do I delete items from the Reading List in OS X/Safari? Little grey X does not show up, which is what it says to click on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear ALL items from Safari's reading list?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96849/how-to-clear-all-items-from-safaris-reading-list)

Comment: @fsb, NKO is not asking explicitly asking how to clear all as in what you are pointing to as a possible duplicate.

Comment: @NKO, When I have my Reading List showing, I have to mouse-over any given item in the list for the close (x) button to show for that item. It appears in the upper right-hand side corner of the item. Are your sure the Browser has focus when mousing-over the Reading List?

Comment: OP indicated "items" so it could be all. Also, several answers on that question show how to delete individually and OP didn't indicate what was already tried other than the 'x'.

Comment: @NKO, What version of Apple's Desktop OS are you running, and what version of Safari?

Comment: Swipe the item to the left and it goes red and offers deletion.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a single item from Safari's Reading List, <kbd>Control</kbd> + **Click**  (or right click) the item and select **Remove Item**:

[image: Reading List Contextual menu]

Answer (score 1):

Like on an iPhone, use 2 fingers and swipe from right-to-left on the Reading List item.  A red button indicating "Remove" will come up.  Just click on that button to remove the item.

Comment: Or just keep swiping!